# delete some characters from string using regex

Tags: java, regex

i have this string:

```
{"json": "{"created_at":"Sun Sep 24 11:10:52"}"}
```

actually i need to delete third and latest Double quotes character (**"**) from string and keep remaining chars like this:

```
{"json": {"created_at":"Sun Sep 24 11:10:52"}}
```

how i deal it with **regex**?

*third and latest Double quotes character (**"**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to create over it, capture what you wan to keep and replace by th capturing groups :

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    String str = "{\"json\": \"{\"created_at\":\"Sun Sep 24 11:10:52\"}\"}\n";
    str = str.replaceAll("(.*:\\s+)\"(\\{.*\\}).*(\\})", "$1$2$3");
    System.out.println(str);   //{"json": {"created_at":"Sun Sep 24 11:10:52"}}
}
```

---

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/t0R4CN/3) - [`Code Demo`](https://ideone.com/UrhI4h)